# Accessing SharePoint Search Statistics via the API

Tags: sharepoint, search

Does anyone know if/how you can retrieve the SharePoint search statistics via the API? We've been asked to build a Tag Cloud based on popular search terms so I want to get the top 10/15 most popular searches (together with their hit count) and build a control out programatically.

Anyone seen this done or can point me in the right direction?

Thanks,
James.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about the API. I do know that there is a stored proc in the shared services db which returns the top search queries. The proc is called "proc_MSS_QLog_TopQueries".

Some of the links which might help
https://sharepoint.missouri.edu/wiki/Wiki%20Pages/MOSS%20Usage%20Reports%20explained.aspx
http://jopx.blogspot.com/2008/04/extending-usage-analysis-reporting-in.html

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for this. I had stumbled my way to this SP also using reflector.